# Upload photos synced from iTunes to iCloud

Tags: iphone, icloud, photos

I have about 1500 photos on my iPhone which I imported from my old HTC Titan, through iTunes. I recently tried to turn on iCloud Photo Library and it said it would delete all my photos from my old phone (!)

How can I combine my old photos with my current ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First upload the old photos using https://www.icloud.com/#photos

Once they are securely uploaded, you can then check that the old photos can safely be deleted since the phone will then re-download them from the cloud.