# Moving from an old IPhone with faulty charge connection to android,

Tags: iphone, android

I'm not a iPhone user so my knowledge is limited.

My mother-in-law has an old iPhone (5 i think) with iOS 10.3.4. It does not charge very well anymore and the pc does not recognize it when connected.

She got a new Android phone and when setting up the iPhone for her it says  you can transfer her photo etc by installing google drive on the old iPhone, but can't install google drive to iOS 10.3.4.  Considering I can't connect the iPhone to the pc and backup that way, what options do I have to get her photos off her phone?

Thanks

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/364567/how-to-upload-photo-library-of-photos-not-taken-with-this-ipad-from-ipad-to-ic#comment485485_364567 this *question* and comment has some suggestions.

Comment: I can't connect to pc/mac as the connection port on the iphone is faulty.  with airdrop i would need a mac? ( don't have access to one)

Comment: uploading to iCloud, or any cloud service which ships for your iPhone. You'd have to look around for that. See reviews for cloud services. Also, see if  https://send.firefox.com can upload from browser.

Comment: If syncing with a PC does not work and you can't install cloud apps you may have to email/text the pictures to another email account and save them out that way.

Comment: Also, see if apps like Xender or other bluetooth file sharing apps can be used. You can also [edit] your question to include all the apps you've considered to avoid repeated suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You have quite a few options, any of these should work, choose the one you like the most:

- I see your cable isn't working properly, but you may try to connect the iPhone to a PC with iTunes for just enough time to enable the [wireless (Wi-Fi) syncing feature](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201253) (press apply to save and enable it). Then, you can create the backup on the PC wirelessly, transfer photos, etc.
- You can try to download Google Photos and let it sync all of her photos. You will lose quality on photos and videos if using the free service, but you may transfer any amount of data this way, and the photos will automatically be on her Android phone if she uses the same Google login on it.
- [Use iCloud Photo Library](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204264). It's available on iOS 10.3 and later. If she has less than 5GB of photos, it's free: enable the iCloud Photo Library on Settings > [her name] > iCloud > Photos and let it sync all of them. You can then download them on any PC from iCloud.com. If she has more than 5GB of photos, you will need to purchase 1 month of the service with the amount you need (from $0.99 for 50GB to $19 if I'm not mistaken for 2TB).

Comment: I'm going to try another lead that I know works with another iphone first ( need to borrow one from someone),  but the i icloud photo library sound like a good solution, I think the phone only has 16gb of storage and after os and apps might be less than 5gb of photos/videos.... heaven forbid I have to pay 99c! ;)

Comment: @PaddyD I too own a 16 GB iPhone and free version works fine for me.

Comment: @PaddyD Did the answer work for you? If so, please mark it as the solution for your question. Thanks

Comment: Haven't had a chance to try anything yet.  But when I do I'll update the question ( I personally hate old questions that are not marked answered)

Answer (score 0):

Install iTunes on a PC and then connect the iPhone to it.

iTunes is a program with specific features to manage data, apps, and store backups for an iPhone. After you've installed it, and perhaps restarted, open iTunes and then connect the iPhone using a standard Apple lightening cable (as [shown here](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MQUE2AM/A/lightning-to-usb-cable-1-m?fnode=97)) to the USB port. Note that there are many non-Apple cables that will NOT allow the iPhone to be recognized, so if you have problems make sure you have an Apple cable.

Of course, another way would be to use someone else's Mac. iTunes comes standard on Macs.

Please ask if this doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/368277/moving-from-an-old-iphone-with-faulty-charge-connection-to-android#comment493074_368277 only sync over Wifi remains.

Comment: Although @ankiiiiiii makes a good point, I'm considering that the poster may be basing his ideas that only sync over Wifi is possible on the statement, "the pc does not recognise it when connected." If there is clear evidence that the connector is not working, then anki is right, but it's worth double-checking that assumption.

Comment: "the pc does not recognise it when connected",  i meant when connected to the PC via USB,  I tried 2 different cables.  The phone has a problem charging ( 8 hrs to get to 50%) it seems the connection on the iphone, but I see if I can borrow a lead from another iphone user that I know works, before ruling that option out,

Comment: Yes, testing with a cable known to work is perfect. Even better would be to connect it to a computer with iTunes that's known to recognize connected iPhones. By the way, my iPhone recently died after symptoms like you describe, so consider acting quickly to get to your data before the battery dies.